# How do I tell windows you are on a carrier network (LTE) so it wouldn't install updates automatically?

Tags: windows-10

Long ago I was able to manipulate some settings to let my Windows on 2-in-1 laptop believe that it is always on a carrier (like LTE) network. This way it didn't bother me with constant updates during the most inconvenient times. But I am unable to repeat or find instructions again. Could you guys point a reference or present steps?

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/948069/174557

Answer (score 0):

If you're using mobile hotspot to share internet with your laptop:

- In setting, navigate to Network & Internet > Wifi > Manage known network
- Choose the network you want to disable auto download update
- Set as metered connection.

If you're using laptop build-in LTE module, as far as i know, metered connection is enabled by default.

If you're on lasted windows 10 update, there're options in update setting that allow you to defer update up to 30 days for big updates and up to 1 year for small updates.

An article you may want to read: [How to set metered connections and disable Windows 10 Update Delivery Optimization](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-disable-windows-10-update-delivery-optimization)